# MySQL JOIN QUERY with MULTIPLE WHERE CLAUSE

Tags: mysql, join

I need some help with MySQL query. Hope someone can help me 'cause Im having a hard time.

Here's my query so far:

```
"SELECT * 
FROM `users` 
JOIN `m_table1` ON users.user_id = m_table1.user_id
JOIN `m_table2` ON users.user_id = m_table2.user_id
JOIN `m_table3` ON users.user_id = m_table3.user_id
WHERE users.user_id=3"
```

I want to add month and year on WHERE clause, but month and year column can be found on tables `m_table1`, `m_table2`, `m_table3`.

Thanks!

Comment: just jam them in the `on clause(s)` where necessary (with AND)

Comment: Provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a visual, tweak any which way. Uses table aliases too for less typing:

```
SELECT u.* 
FROM `users`  u
JOIN `m_table1` t1 ON u.user_id = t1.user_id
JOIN `m_table2` t2 ON u.user_id = t2.user_id and t2.year=1942
JOIN `m_table3` t3 ON u.user_id = t3.user_id and t3.year=1942 and t3.month=7
WHERE u.user_id=3
```

Comment: however, you probably want your first line to be `select u.col1,u.col2,t1.thisCol` sort of thing. Stay away from select *

Comment: Tried your solution and I have edited the first line with specific select column. I got the result that I want. You're so helpful, thanks!

Comment: I have my moments, my pleasure